# How to allow VPN client to use their local internet for browsing

Tags: iptables, routing, vpn, strongswan

I have configured Ikev2 VPN server road warrior using strongswan package on centos 8
and it works fine. when clients connect they use remote site internet for browsing how to allow client to use their internet here is below my IP tables and firewall rules.

iptables -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N LIBVIRT_INP
-N LIBVIRT_OUT
-N LIBVIRT_FWO
-N LIBVIRT_FWI
-N LIBVIRT_FWX
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

iptables -S INPUT

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
```

iptables -S OUTPUT

```
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootpc

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

firewall-cmd --list-all

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno1 enp0s20f0u14
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ipsec openvpn ssh
  ports: 500/udp 4500/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule protocol value="esp" accept
    rule protocol value="ah" accept
```

iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [27115:3345403]
:INPUT ACCEPT [69:9680]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3405:252395]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [214:16188]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [65756:14700930]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [78940:39400265]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [48913:35869992]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [47156:11962633]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [78894:39398425]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [48920:35871732]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [150103:54480128]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [48922:35872348]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [150103:54480128]
:INPUT ACCEPT [65757:14700982]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [78940:39400265]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [48923:35872484]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [127964:75288423]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 28 12:39:48 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split tunneling; set the routes to 0.0.0.0 to route via local network, and set the routes to the office network (10.0.0.0 ?) to route via the VPN.

Comment: thank you for your response can you please explain little bit more ?

Comment: It's just a matter of routing your traffic. Your VPN connection has an interface which is the gateway to the network on the other side of the VPN, such as your office; explicitly send all of your traffic to that particular network using that VPN interface as a gateway. Then Send all of the other traffic (0.0.0.0)  through the interface that is connected to your ISP.